# hidapi ./configure error --- missing libudev

Tags: debian, usb

I am trying to install hidapi on Debian.  I already have libudev-dev and libusb-1.0-0-dev installed, but when I run ./configure in hidapi-master, it says that I do not have libudev, to install it and retry.  I am not sure how to fix this.  Any help concerning this is appreciated.  Thank you.

Exact error

```
checking for libudev... no
Library libudev was not found on this system.
Please install it and re-run ./configure
```

locate libudev

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0
/usr/share/doc/libudev0
/usr/share/doc/libudev0/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libudev0/README.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libudev0/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/libudev0/README.keymap.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/libudev0/TODO
/usr/share/doc/libudev0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libudev0/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/libudev0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libudev0/udev.vim
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libudev0:i386.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libudev0:i386.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libudev0:i386.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libudev0:i386.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libudev0:i386.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libudev0:i386.symbols
```

Comment: Can you show the exact error? Your title says `missing libudev` but your body says `I do not have libusb`.

Comment: You could look at the `configure` script to see what it is actually testing for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tough one because everything was there. After a system reboot, the `libudev.a` appeared in `/usr/lib` for some reason. I had two versions of package config on my system (not sure how that happened) and `./configure` for hidapi was using the wrong one.

This was solved by adding this path to `/root/.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config libusb-dev
./configure && make
```

---

Did you also install `libusb-dev` too?

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

Comment: Yes I have, it says that they're already the newest version

Comment: Updated my post. I ran that on Ubuntu 14 and it worked.

Comment: I have noticed that apt-get did not give me all of the files I [need](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libudev-dev/filelist).  The first command does not install anything new for me.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I cannot find the source code for libudev.  How can I get the .a library then?

Comment: Are you trying to build hidapi from the git repo `http://github.com/signal11/hidapi.git` ?

Comment: yes, I am; I cannot get this [udev source code](https://code.launchpad.net/udev) to install either

Comment: do I need libudev.a for this to work?  Debian apt-get does not give it to me like what Ubuntu does seemingly

Answer (score 1):

Use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get install` :

```
sudo aptitude install libudev-dev
```